How to get return code of command run before bash script?
$ beep; echo $?

Command 'beep' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install beep
Please ask your administrator.

127

$ cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $?

The expected output of my script should be "127".
Why, then, after executing the bash script in the same manner, the return code printed is not what we expect?
$ beep; ./test.sh

Command 'beep' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install beep
Please ask your administrator.

0


Your script is executed by a fresh bash process. It doesn't know what the caller is doing or what its internal variables are set to

$? is not inherited by child processes.
You can export it to an environment variable, and check that in the script.
test.sh:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $CODE

then
beep
CODE=$? ./test.sh

Or you could pass $? as a script parameter:
test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "$1"

then
beep; ./test.sh $?

